# Acesso ao arquivo de remessa boleto .NET

Tags: c#

Estou usando o boleto .NET para geração de boletos em minha aplicação.

O boleto é gerado, porém como eu processo o arquivo de remessa? Esse arquivo é salvo em algum lugar da aplicação?

Peguei o exemplo do projeto que está no Git, porém não sei como processar o arquivo de remessa gerado, aliás não sei nem aonde é salvo.

```
//cedente
String cedente_codigo = "1111111";
String cedente_nossoNumeroBoleto = "22222222";
String cedente_Cnpj = "000.000.000-00";
String cedente_nome = "Nome do Cendete.";
String cedente_agencia = "0000";
String cedente_conta = "00000";
String cedente_digitoConta = "0";

Cedente cedente = new Cedente(cedente_Cnpj, cedente_nome, cedente_agencia, cedente_conta);

// Na carteira 198 o código do Cedente é a conta bancária
cedente.Codigo = "13000";

Boleto boleto = new Boleto(vencimento, valorPagamento, "176", "00000001", cedente,
                           new EspecieDocumento(341, "1")); //banco 341 - Itau

boleto.NumeroDocumento = "00000001";            

boleto.Sacado = new Sacado(cliente.Cnpj, cliente.NomeFantasia);
boleto.Sacado.Endereco.End = cliente.Logradouro;
boleto.Sacado.Endereco.Bairro = cliente.Bairro;
boleto.Sacado.Endereco.Cidade = cliente.Cidade.Nome;
boleto.Sacado.Endereco.CEP = cliente.Cep;
boleto.Sacado.Endereco.UF = cliente.Estado.Sigla;
boletoBancario.GerarArquivoRemessa = true;
boletoBancario.Boleto = boleto;
boletoBancario.Boleto.Valida();

Boletos boletos = new Boletos();
boletos.Add(boleto);

// geração do arquivo de remessa - Feito com a ajuda de jbueno
var objRemessa = new ArquivoRemessa(TipoArquivo.CNAB400);
var memoryStr = new MemoryStream();

objRemessa.GerarArquivoRemessa("09", new Banco(341), cedente, boletos, memoryStr, 1000);

if (Session["boleto"] != null)
    Session.Remove("boleto");
    Session["boleto"] = boletoBancario.MontaHtmlEmbedded();
```

Comment: Olá Raul, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Sua pergunta não oferece um exemplo de código e informações suficientes para que alguém possa diagnosticar o seu problema. De uma olhada em [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) na [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: objRemessa.GerarArquivoRemessa("09", new Banco(341), cedente, boletos, memoryStr, 1000); Qual o caminho que o arquivo é gerado ?

Comment: @Diego se não me engano quando vc declara o memoryStr é possível determinar um caminho, tipo: var memoryStr = new MemoryStream("C:\Pasta_A"). Ve se da certo, eu não lembro e não trabalho mais na empresa onde fiz o código. :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você é quem gera o arquivo de remessa, na hora de gerá-lo é definido define o caminho que vai salvar o arquivo.

Veja o exemplo de uma geração de arquivo remessa completa (do banco Bradesco, mas a única coisa que muda de um banco pro outro são as regras de negócio dos campos).

```
var objCedente = new Cedente("12345678000155", "TESTE", "1111", "11234", "1");
objCEDENTE.Codigo = "123456";
objCEDENTE.Convenio = 9;

//Instância de Boleto
var objBOLETO = new Boleto();
objBOLETO.EspecieDocumento = new EspecieDocumento(237,"12");
objBOLETO.DataVencimento = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
objBOLETO.ValorBoleto = 90;
objBOLETO.Carteira ="09";
objBOLETO.NossoNumero = ("00000012345");
objBOLETO.Cedente = objCEDENTE;
objBOLETO.NumeroDocumento = "1234567890";
objBOLETO.DataDocumento = DateTime.Now;
objBOLETO.DataProcessamento = DateTime.Now;
objBOLETO.Sacado = new Sacado("12345678000255", "TESTE SACADO");
objBOLETO.Sacado.Endereco.End = "END SACADO";
objBOLETO.Sacado.Endereco.Bairro = "BAIRRO SACADO";
objBOLETO.Sacado.Endereco.Cidade = "CIDADE SACADO";
objBOLETO.Sacado.Endereco.CEP = "CEP SACADO";
objBOLETO.Sacado.Endereco.UF = "RR";

objBOLETO.PercMulta = 10;
objBOLETO.JurosMora = 5;

Boletos objBOLETOS = new Boletos();
objBOLETOS.Add(objBOLETO);

var memoryStr = new MemoryStream();
var objREMESSA = new ArquivoRemessa(TipoArquivo.CNAB400);
objREMESSA.GerarArquivoRemessa("09", new Banco(237), objCEDENTE, objBOLETOS, memoryStr, 1000);
```

Comment: Beleza, muito obrigado. Nesse exemplo que você escreveu vc não definiu o lugar onde local onde está sendo salvo o boleto, correto? Esse local eu defino em alguma configuração?

Comment: jbuneo eu testei seu código com o projeto boleto.net e não consegui gerar o arquivo.

Comment: Consegui arrumar o erro. Antes de pedir para gerar o arquivo de remessa, é preciso validar o boleto.

Comment: @RaulPeresdeGóes Se a resposta do jbueno atendeu a tua pergunta marque-a como "aceita".

Comment: Gerei o txt do boleto (arquivo de remessa) a partir da leitura do memory stream.